# Will the water stay in a falling glass?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, newtonian-gravity, reference-frames, home-experiment

Everyday experience tells me that a glass filled with water will fall and  smash on the ground as a whole object as it started (water and glass together), given that it falls face up and it does not rotate, or flip while falling.
Is my intuition right?
I know that in absence of friction all objects fall at the same rate, but I'm trying to analyze an everyday situation so air resistance must be taken in account!
Been knowing that there is friction exerted on the glass and on the water,
Will there be different outcomes if I use different types of glasses?
Let's say a plastic glass (Can I say that? I hope) and a ( glass) glass ahah.
I came up with some theories but they're long to eplain anyway I will post a link in the comment if somone has curiosity or time to read it!

Comment: Do you think I should edit the question?

Comment: Wait I made a mistake not considering friciton! I neeed to add something I'll try to edit the question!

Comment: Did you intend to neglect air resistance?

Comment: Did you know that regardless of their mass, objects fall at the same speed?

Comment: No no I'm very tired right now so I forgot to underline that there is air resistance, otherwise my question has no sense I think

Comment: Is the glass falling right way up or upside down? how high is it falling from? If it is falling from human heights, the air resistance is going to be negligible as it won't have time to reach terminal velocity. If it is falling from hundreds of meters up, then I would have no idea.

Comment: @A.C.A.C. I edited to make it more clear

Comment: What difference do you expect air resistance to make?

Answer (score 0):

Depends if there is rotation and air turbulence against the water's surface.

If the glass falls straight down without rotation, and the water faces upwards, there is no force to push the water out.

If the glass rotates, you can have air that pushes the water out.

'Water getting out' means there are forces pushing against the water's surface away from the glass (to the side, to the top of the glass). Air cannot do that if you are falling straight down with the face pointing upwards. Unless you generate enough turbulence that a vortex pulls the water up and out of the glass.

Comment: The capilar force would push water out, but may not be enough to push out much or fight the air resistance.